# 2 circles want to show us something

Tags: visual, rebus

What symbol / sign does this picture want to show us?

[image]

It is not number 8

Hint 1

> My life revolve around you

Hint 2

> top circle revolve around the other circle

Comment: Nice, but the second hint is too strong, I believe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm inclined to say you're looking for a

> Cardioid or heart

Because

> It's what you get from rolling the circle above with the red dot as a marker
>  [image: It's what you get from rolling the circle above with the red dot as a marker]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

> DNA Replication, but since this would be bacterial DNA replication and it doesn't explain the rebus tag.

Comment: Stronk Engrish is stronk